# prevening visual stuidio project has change dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I have written a MsBuild task that may change the project file it is within.  All works fine however I get do get the project has changed dialog when I build the project in visual studio.

Can any one help me with how (within a Visual Studio extension on a BuildEvent I assume) to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I don't know of any way to achieve this. msbuild is exactly as any other app when it comes to the Visual Studio IDE considering it "external". The file listener will detect that the file was modified externally. To avoid it you'll have to go through VS APIs but those are only available from the IDE.

Comment: As you say what in need to do is create a vsix (I am using VS 2015 FYI) to extend VS to prevent it from listening to the file change.  My question is how do I do that.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudio-SharedProject/blob/master/Product/SharedProject/SuspendFileChanges.cs) and placed Suspend in OnBuildProjConfigBegin and Resume in OnBuildProjConfigDone (events from EnvDTE.Events.BuildEvents)  but this did not work. I did note IVsDocDataFileChangeControl interface was not supported by the object returned from FindAndLockDocument)

Comment: Making these changes to csproj files from a VSIX extension also does not make any difference if you access the file directly. I do that extensively on our VS extensions using the Microsoft.Build.Evaluation namespace. But I don't really mind the dialog.

Comment: May be you can inspect the NuGet implementation. They do changes to the csproj files without the dialog appearing. I never studied that implementation.